# Use field calculator QGIS: if value in one column, then value in new column

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, string, calculate-values, regular-expression

I am having troubles using the field calculator to get what I want. 
One column in my attribute table is named 'Taxa' and has a set of species in it. Species are separated by #.

I want to make a new column using the field calculator that returns a value, based on the species in the 'Taxa' column.

An example of the column I want to use to calculate a value in the new column:
[image: 'Taxa' column example]
Below i have some examples of values per species:

```
Calluna_vulgaris =1
Baeomyces_rufus = 1
Porpidia_crustulata =2
Rhizocarpon reductum =2
Micarea_erratica = 2
Hypnum_jutlandicum = 1/3
```

To summarize: If the Taxa column says 'Calluna_vulgaris#Porpidia_crustulata#Micarea_erratica'

I want the new column to have the number 5.

I understand this is not the most convenient way to group species in a column, but I used the TomBio addon which does this automatically.

Comment: So you need to sum up the values from your list if the associated name does exist in column Taxa? For your example 1+2+2=5? And if it is `Calluna_vulgaris#Baeomyces_rufus` then it should be 1+1=2? How big is your entire list? Do you have it available as CSV or something you can import to QGIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the most robust method for you will involve having your species-value list on another layer as a CSV or similar -  in other words, a lookup table. Trying to match values in expressions will be incredibly inefficient, difficult to edit, and prone to error.

It should be easy to create such a table in any spreadsheet program, even a basic text editor, then import it into QGIS using Add Delimited Text Layer. (Make sure to trim fields so that no extra spaces make their way in)

Once you have that you could use the following expression (built on @csk's excellent suggestion to use arrays) to return the values required and sum them together. If one or more species cannot be found in the lookup table it will return a `NULL` which should prompt the user to check the data.

---

This is the lookup table I have set up called `taxa_csv` in the layers list (note the name).

[image]

This is the expression I used in field calculator (note lookup table name is in expression).

```
eval(replace(array_to_string(array_foreach(string_to_array("taxa",'#'),
to_real(attribute(get_feature('taxa_csv','taxon',@element),'value'))),',','NULL'),',','+'))
```

Result - note `NULL`s for entries where species not in lookup table.

[image]

---

Some notes:

- The lookup table name (`taxa_csv`) and corresponding column names (`taxon`, `value`) in the expression are **case-sensitive**. If you rename the lookup table and/or column names, just remember to change the names accordingly in this expression.
- Even if your source values are all text (e.g. CSV) the expression will convert it to a numeric format (`to_real()`). (However, `1/3` won't work - I suggest converting this to a decimal number)
- If you want to treat species not found as `0` rather than `NULL` replace accordingly in the expression. I don't recommend this though as it can be misleading
- Does anyone know a good way to sum everything in an array in QGIS Field Calc? Had to kludge it together by converting back to a string and replacing commas with plus signs then evaluating it with `eval()`

Comment: Thanks, i tried all methods but ended up liking this one the most. 
Thanks for the solution! Works perfect!

Comment: Starting with QGIS 3.18 array_sum was introduced:
array_sum(array_foreach(string_to_array("taxa",'#'),
to_real(attribute(get_feature('taxa_csv','taxon',@element),'value'))))

Answer (score 7):

You can use `regexp_match` function to find starting position of the word within the  string. Than with using condition `if` you can test if there is string occurence (e.g. starting position > 0) and set the value for `TRUE` (your value) and `FALSE` (0).

It should look like this:

```
if(regexp_match(taxa, 'Calluna_vulgaris')>0,1,0) +
if(regexp_match(taxa, 'Porpidia_crustulata')>0,2,0) +
if(regexp_match(taxa, 'Rhizocarpon reductum')>0,2,0) +
if(regexp_match(taxa, 'Micarea_erratica')>0,2,0)
```

[image]

Maybe there is better regexp solution, but I'm not so regexp *ninja*.

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to use the `replace` function repeatedly to replace the species names with their corresponding values, replace the # signs with + signs, then use `eval` to calculate the sum. Eg,

```
eval(
 replace(
  replace(
   replace(
    replace(
     replace(
      replace(
       replace("Taxa",'Baeomyces_rufus', 1),
      'Calluna_vulgaris',1),
     'Porpidia_crustulata',2),
    'Rhizocarpon reductum',2),
   'Micarea_erratica', 2),
  'Hypnum_jutlandicum', 0.33333),
 '#','+'))
```

It's pretty cumbersome, though.

---

I suspect there's a possible clever solution using arrays, but I haven't quite worked it out. Here's what I have so far:

- Use `string_to_array("Taxa", '#')` to convert the "Taxa" field to an array
- Create an array with all the possible species names, and create another array with their corresponding values *in the same order*. Using the example you gave, those arrays would look like this:

  - All_Taxa : `('Calluna_vulgaris', 'Baeomyces_rufus', 'Porpidia_crustulata', 'Rhizocarpon_reductum', 'Micarea_erratica', 'Hypnum_jutlandicum')`
  - All_Values: `(1,1,2,2,2,0.3333)`
- Use `array_find` on every value from the "Taxa" array, to find its position within the All_Taxa array. Then use `array_get` to retrieve the corresponding values from the All_Values array.

  - The `array_filter` function might be useful - you could filter the All_Values array based on an expression that achieves the above.

Comment: I think a map would be better than an array for the species name and values. You would have an expression like `array_foreach(string_to_array("taxa",'#'),map_get(map('Calluna_vulgaris',1,'Baeomyces_rufus',1,'Porpidia_crustulata',2,'Rhizocarpon_reductum',2,'Micarea_erratica',2,'Hypnum_jutlandicum',0.333),@element))` That way you don't need to worry about order and the key-value pairs are more obvious.

Comment: I don't know about maps. I'll have to look into that. It sounds useful.

Comment: Starting with QGIS 3.18 array_sum was introduced: 
`array_sum(
array_foreach(
string_to_array("taxa",'#'),
map_get(
map(
'Calluna_vulgaris',1,
'Baeomyces_rufus',1,
'Porpidia_crustulata',2,
'Rhizocarpon_reductum',2,
'Micarea_erratica',2,
'Hypnum_jutlandicum',0.333,
'Erica_tetralix',2,
'Carex_pilulifera',1.5),
@element)))`

Comment: @pigreco That could be a whole answer by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression:

```
(Taxa ~ 'Calluna_vulgaris') * 1 +
(Taxa ~ 'Baeomyces_rufus') * 1 +
(Taxa ~ 'Porpidia_crustulata') * 2 +
(Taxa ~ 'Rhizocarpon reductum') * 2 +
(Taxa ~ 'Micarea_erratica') * 2+ 
(Taxa ~ 'Hypnum_jutlandicum') / 3
```

To [operator `~`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#id60) performs a regular expression match: 1 if true, 0 if zero. So in line 1: if field `Taxa` contains `'Calluna_vulgaris'`, it returns 1. So just multiply with the values associated with each species and add the values. If the string is not contained, result is 0 and nothing is added.

[image]

You could iterate through the repeating part of the expression with `array_foreach()` and usings maps:

```
array_sum(
    with_variable(
        'mp',
        map(
            'Calluna_vulgaris',1,
            'Baeomyces_rufus',1,
            'Porpidia_crustulata',2,
            'Rhizocarpon reductum',2,
            'Micarea_erratica',2,
            'Hypnum_jutlandicum',1/3
        ),
        array_foreach(map_akeys(@mp),
            eval ('("Taxa" ~ '''  || @element  || ''') * '  || map_get(@mp,@element))
        )
    )
)
```